# install4j - looking to change the name of 'updates.xml'

Tags: install4j

Is there any way to change the name of the 'updates.xml' file created by install4j during the build?

I know I can rename the file after the build runs, and then have a custom URL on my server, but we have multiple builds that run in parallel on different threads.  And they all put their output into the same media folder.  As things stand now, the updates.xml can get overwritten by a different thread.

I think I am looking for an option to control the name to something like 'myprog_updates.xml', using a compiler variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 7.0.8 there is no way to do that. Starting with 7.0.9 you will be able to change the file name by setting the compiler variable `sys.ext.updatesFileName` on the "General Settings->Compiler Variables" step.

Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented.